# Code to shorten specified numbers in column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set up a code to read a series of numbers in a column and return a specified shorter number. For example, if the number is 200 then this would return the number 1 and 400 would return 2. Any thoughts if this is possible?

Comment: When you say 'return a specified shorter number', do you mean you have a list of shorter numbers and you want to find which one corresponds to a particular large number?

Comment: Also, is there any formula that maps the numbers to their shortened form? e.x. 200 / 200 = 1, 400 / 200 = 2, ... x / 200 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example with a double loop:

```
Sub Shorten()
    Dim ary(1 To 4) As Long, bry(1 To 4) As Long
    Dim I As Long, N As Long

    ary(1) = 100
    ary(2) = 234
    ary(3) = 8765
    ary(4) = 123
    bry(1) = 1
    bry(2) = 2
    bry(3) = 3
    bry(4) = 4
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 1 To N
        For j = 1 To 4
            If Cells(I, 1).Value = ary(j) Then Cells(I, 1).Value = bry(j)
        Next j
    Next I
End Sub
```

ary() contains the list of "long" values and bry() the list of "shorter" values.

Comment: Thank you this has worked well. A slight issue is that it is only amending the number in column A of the datasheet. How do I specify the column from which to run the macro? Also, is there a way to run the macro automatically when the column is populated with the long numbers?